# SymGEigsShiftSolver vs SymGEigsSolver

Tags: numerical-methods, spectra

I don't know where to ask the question but since I am implementing an algorithm using this library I think is more appropriate here:

I've been using Spectra for generalized eigen values problems specifically I've been using [SymGEigsSolver](https://spectralib.org/doc/classspectra_1_1symgeigssolver) and I went with it, it seems to work ok. I came across however [SymGEigsShiftSolver](https://spectralib.org/doc/classspectra_1_1symgeigsshiftsolver) which seems to solve a slightly different problem therefore I wonder what the difference are and what is reccomended based on what situation (from an actual programming perspective).

I think more theoretical questions are more suitable for mathoverlow or mathexchange.

Can anyone clarify when should I use one or the other? Is the Shift Solver more stable or converges faster than the normal Solver?

Comment: Questions about algorithms are better placed on scicomp.SE. But before that, please read the ARPACK user guide, and what is said there about method selection. Or about the Arnoldi/Lanczos method and variants of its application.

Comment: Is it possible to move this question there?